# How do you load HTML file in .Net fileupload and automatically preview it on iFrame

Tags: c#, .net, iframe, file-upload

I have fileupload.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="iptDestinatarios" runat="server"  style="position:relative;top:8px;left:28px;"/>
```

I use it to select HTML file from local computer, once i select the file i need to preview it inside iFrame, what is the best solution?

Comment: What sort of file can it be?

Comment: After you select the file and before it is uploaded, or after it is uploaded?